# jquery hover mouseout when form select field extends outside toggle container

Tags: jquery, forms, select, hover

First, here is the html

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='toolBar'></div>
  <div class='element'>
    <a href="#"><img src=''/></a>
    <form>
      <select name='albumSelect' class='albumSelect'></select>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using jquery so that when the container is hovered it shows the form, and hides on mouseout. Of course the problem is that when the select field is too long you lose hover on the container element and the form disappears.

Should i test if the form has focus, and if so do not hide the form on mouseout? What would be a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

If i would have been then for no extra pain adjusted the `size of select box using css`!